# Network Connection awareness in Unix Operating System

Tags: unix, networking

I know that Windows has two services to determine if the system has access to the internet: Network Location Awareness (NLA) and -List Service. Basically it will become active when your network situation changes, checks the IP the system resolves for a certain hostname, does an HTTP request for a .txt file on this site and verifies the content in this text file (for example, msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt).

How do unixoid operating systems (Linux, MacOS, iOS, Android) determine if they are connected to the Internet?  Similiar deamons to NLA?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no equivalent service in Linux. The way Windows NLA system works is that a service automatically requests a file from a Microsoft website every time you connect to any network, and the result of this attempt tells it whether the connection is successful. I am not sure how useful this feature is, but some may have privacy concerns with sending their IP address to Microsoft (which the site logs, according to documentation) every single time they connect to the internet. This may be a reason such a service may not exist in Linux world.

Here is a [good article](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/) to read.